# Context is null in Lifecycle aware LiveEvent

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My project is currently using the following `SingleLiveEvent` implementation.

```
class SingleLiveEvent<T>(
    private val allowMultipleObservers: Boolean = false
) : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val mPending = AtomicBoolean(false)
    private val observers = mutableSetOf<Observer<in T>>()

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(
        owner: LifecycleOwner,
        observer: Observer<in T>
    ) {

        if (!allowMultipleObservers && hasActiveObservers()) {
            Timber.tag(TAG)
                .w("Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
        } else {
            observers.add(observer)
        }

        // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
        super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->
            if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observers.forEach { observer ->
                    observer.onChanged(t)
                }
            }
        })
    }
...
```

When we do this inside of `onResume` or `onCreateView`

```
SingleLiveEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
   requireContext()
}
```

We sometimes receive a crash saying that the `Context` is null. However, shouldn't `requireContext()` always give us a valid `Context` value since it's attached to the `viewLifecycleOwner`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is flawed - it's possible to register multiple observers as long as they attach in inactive state (or existing observers became inactive), then observer wrapper you passed to `super.observe` will fail because you're forcing a call to `onChanged` for all observers disregarding their actual state.

You should replace `hasActiveObservers()` with `hasObservers()`. But personally I'd look into solution implementing `MediatorLiveData` since this implementation doesn't properly handle observers that enter destroyed state, leaving them in your `observers` list forever.

Comment: 100% thank you, I just saw that. Will look into that solution with `MediatorLiveData` or just a different solution for this hacky implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`requireContext()` does nothing special except for null-check comparing to `getContext()`.

#### Answer from Google:

How should we fix that?
Firstly we should fix potentials bugs.

- Find all places where fragment can be detached at some point of time
- Change code like in the sample below

In Java:

```
Context context = getContext();
if (context == null) {
    // Handle null context scenario
} else {
    // Old code with context
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@shafran/fragment-getcontext-vs-requirecontext-ffc9157d6bbe